# How to support ftp command in yocto?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

In my yocto image, it do not support ftp:

```
ftp: command not found
```

Is there any recipe that supports ftp?

Comment: Install any ftp client. You could find a list here: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-networking/

Comment: Or modify the busybox config and add the ftp commands, if using busybox.

Comment: how to modify busybox config?

Answer (score 0):

busybox provides no ftp client. detailed answer is [here](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2002-June/040388.html).

only **ftpget** and **ftpput** non-interactive commands are available in busybox.

openembedded provides recipe called: **ncftp**

"a sophisticated console ftp client"